# How do I convert a color value created by the Win32 API Function "ChooseColor " into a css compatible rgb hex value

Tags: .net, winapi, colors

I have a value created by the win32 api function [ChooseColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646912.aspx) and I want to convert it into a rgb hex tripplet. How do I do this. What exactly is the number returned by ChooseColor?

Comment: Why are you not using the System.Windows.Forms.ColorDialog class?  It is a wrapper class for ChooseColor().  Avoids the conversion hassle.

Comment: The color is defined in another application. I just read the values from a database and need to convert it into an rbg hex tripple value, so I can use it in css/jquery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you're doing this in .NET, you can use the `COLORREF` value and convert to a .NET colour using:

```
Color colour = ColorTranslator.FromWin32(myColorRef);
```

If you then want it as an HTML hex triplet string:

```
string htmlColour = ColorTranslator.ToHTML(colour);
```

Answer (score 3):

When returning, the CHOOSECOLOR structure contains `rgbResult`, which is an RGB value packed into a 32-bit COLORREF value (using 24 bits). In C++, you can use the [GetRValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144923.aspx), GetGValue and GetBValue macros to get the components.

Comment: Is there some way to call this macros from .net?

Answer (score 0):

Some documents that might aid you in this:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646912(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646830(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646830%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You need to use the **rgbResult** of your ChooseColor.

There is an example here -> [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646829(v=vs.85).aspx#choosing_color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646829%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#choosing_color)

Answer (score 0):

[`COLORREF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183449.aspx):

> When specifying an explicit RGB color, the COLORREF value has the
>   following hexadecimal form:
>
> 0x00bbggrr
>
> The low-order byte contains a value for the relative intensity of red;
>   the second byte contains a value for green; and the third byte
>   contains a value for blue. The high-order byte must be zero. The
>   maximum value for a single byte is 0xFF.
>
> To create a COLORREF color value, use the RGB macro. To extract the
>   individual values for the red, green, and blue components of a color
>   value, use the **GetRValue**, **GetGValue**, and **GetBValue** macros,
>   respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the documentation of `ChooseColor()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646912.aspx), the "number" returned by it is just a boolean saying whether the user selected some color or not.

The value of the color is filled into [the `CHOOSECOLOR` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646830.aspx) that you pass as the only argument, specifically, in its `rgbResult` field.

If you define [the `COLORREF` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183449.aspx), which is the type of the `rgbResult` field, according to [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/COLORREF.html) as:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct COLORREF {
   public byte R;
   public byte G;
   public byte B;
}
```

Then you can get the RGB values by accessing the `R`, `G` and `B` fields.